# Blocking recv doesn't exit when closing socket from another thread?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In Linux if we call blocking `recv` from one thread and close for the same socket from another thread, `recv` doesn't exit.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that all file descriptors for the socket have been closed. If any remain open at the "remote end" (assuming this is the one you attempt to close), the "[peer has not performed an orderly shutdown](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv)".

If this still doesn't work, call [`shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) on the remote end, this will shut the socket down regardless of reference counts.

Answer (score 14):

The "why" is simply that that's how it works, by design.

Within the kernel, the `recv()` call has called `fget()` on the `struct file` corresponding to the file descriptor, and this will prevent it from being deallocated until the corresponding `fput()`.

You will simply have to change your design (your design is inherently racy anyway - for this to happen, you must have no locking protecting the file descriptor in userspace, which means that the `close()` could have happened just *before* the `recv()` call - and the file descriptor even been reused for something else).

---

If you want to wake up another thread that's blocking on a file descriptor, you should have it block on `select()` instead, with a pipe included in the file descriptor set that can be written to by the main thread.

Comment: if I call close before calling recv, it should work, but once the call is in recv, and if I call close from another thread, it doesn't get deallocated. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jay: Once you've called `close()`, you should *not* call `recv()` on the file descriptor.  If you're lucky you'll just get `EBADF`, but if you're unlucky you could read from a completely different socket newly opened by another thread.

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  Pater is trying to call close() on a socket that is ALREADY inside of recv() to force recv() to exit immediately.  This works on other systems, but is not working on Linux.

Comment: @Remy: I know that, and as I said in my answer - that behaviour is by design.  My first comment is in relation to the OPs comment.