# closing a socket after failing to send data doesn't cause recv function to return with error status

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm wondering why closing a `socket` with the standard `close` function without a prior call to the `shutdown` function after failing to sending data due to an unavailable peer doesn't cause a `recv` function on the same `socket` to return ?

pseudo code:

```
void sendData()
{
  ::send(socket_,...);
  if(error)
     close(socket_); //recv still block after this call
}

void worker()
{
   while(1)
   {
      ::recv(socket_...)

      if(error)
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624365/blocking-recv-doesnt-exit-when-closing-socket-from-another-thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. It causes `recv()` to exit with an *end of stream* status.

Your code never examines the return value, so it can never detect that it's zero. You need to store the result into a variable; check it for -1 indicating an error; check it for zero indicating end of stream; and otherwise use it as the length of the data returned.