# How to make send and recv methods work simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

Send and recv methods working fine but when I send quit the recv method keeps in loop. I don't know much about multi-threading. When I send 'Q' the connection should close properly and it has to listen for clients.

How to make serve for multiple clients simultaneously?

```
int main()
{
    if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) {
        cerr<<"unable to listen for clients"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout<<"TCPServer Waiting for client on port 8000"<<endl;
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
    thread sds(snds),rvs(rcvs);
    if(sds.joinable()){
        sds.join();
    }
    if(rvs.joinable()){
        rvs.join();
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

void rcvs(){
    while(1){
        bytes_received = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
        recv_data[bytes_received] = '';
        srz_rcv=recv_data;
        mb.ParseFromString(srz_rcv);
        srz_rcv=mb.msg();
        if (strcmp(srz_rcv.c_str() , "q") == 0 || strcmp(srz_rcv.c_str() , "Q") == 0){
            goto FINISH;
        }
        else{
            cout<<inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr)<<" : "<<srz_rcv<<endl;
        }
        mb.Clear();
    }
    FINISH:
    close(connected);
    exit(0);
}
void snds(){
    while(1){
        cout<<"sent : ";
        cin>>send_data;
        mb.set_msg(send_data);
        mb.SerializeToString(&srz_snd);
        if (strcmp(srz_snd.c_str() , "q") == 0 || strcmp(srz_snd.c_str() , "Q") == 0){
            send(connected, srz_snd.c_str(),1024, 0);
            goto FINISH;
        }
        else{
            send(connected, srz_snd.c_str(),mb.ByteSize(), 0);
        }
        mb.Clear();
    }
    FINISH:
    close(connected);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Proper indentation matters, please fix yours.

Comment: Post **all** of your code.  For example, what is `recv_data`?

Comment: server: http://pastebin.com/dMtwiiuP client: http://pastebin.com/yPm3kN25

Comment: If you want to serve N clients simultaneously, you better launch N threads. One thread for reading and one for writing don't make much sense.

Comment: @n.m., why are you saying this? This is not true at all.

Comment: If you want to serve multiple clients at the same time, you should either use non-blocking socket IO and multiplex on it, or you should have several processing threads. Btw, get rid of `goto`, it is nasty.

Comment: @SergeyA What exactly is not true?

Comment: @n.m., 'One thread for reading and one for writing don't make much sense.' is not true. As a matter of fact, they make **perfect** sense.

Comment: @SergeyA For a server? No. A server reads a request, then sends out a response. These thing never happen simultaneously. Well, almost never, but that's a long story. You certainly should not start with that.

Comment: @n.m., ever looked into NodeJS architecture?

Comment: Does NodeJS have exactly two threads, one for reading and one for writing? If yes. I'd love to read the code. If not, this has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be closing the accepted socket when you send a "Q" or "q". If you are testing this while running both the client and server in the same process, a blocking `recv` might not return if you do a `close( socket )`. See [Blocking recv doesn't exit when closing socket from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624365/blocking-recv-doesnt-exit-when-closing-socket-from-another-thread) The answers there suggest you can call `shutdown` before `close`. Another option is to change your `recv` to non-blocking and block on `select` instead, since that gives you more control over the conditions of the thread's wait.

On the other hand, if the "Q" or "q" is sent by a client running in a different process, your code "should" work as long as the string comparison succeeds. However, when dealing with TCP sockets, it is always advisable to shut them down gracefully. See [Properly close a TCP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872988/properly-close-a-tcp-socket) Doing a `shutdown` and handling the subsequent read failure/fin on the remote end of the socket before doing a `close` is the suggested method.

Comment: Can you add more details from those sources?